# Huge gaps in backend since 2.4.3, content shifted under the menu

Tags: magento2, admin, backend, magento2.4.2, magento2.4.3

I have had some issues since upgrading to 2.4.4. Some backend pages are loading with a huge gap until the content is visible, which is shifted under the menu too. Reloading with CTRL + F5 solves the problem usually but that's not a solution. The display error only appears sometimes.

Here is a little part of the page how the display error looks, as you can see the content is shifted to a weird location

[image: here is a little part of the page how it looks, as you can see the content is shifted to a weird location]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Chrome extension named Scrnli Screenshot & Screen Video Recorder is messing up the Magento 2 backend

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/scrnli-screenshot-screen/ijejnggjjphlenbhmjhhgcdpehhacaal

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable All third party extension first.
Then run following commands and then check.

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/
```

Comment: I disabled ALL third party extensions but the error still comes up when signing in to the Magento 2 admin dashboard. I noticed there are two keys where one of them has the status 302, is this normal? See https://i.imgur.com/Y7abBlO.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command it may be a deploy issue

sudo chmod -R 777 var/ generated/ pub/
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

Comment: Still having the same issues

Answer (score 0):

The Google Chrome extension named
Koala Inspector - Shopify Spy & Dropship Tool
also il messing up the Magento 2 backend

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/koala-inspector-shopify-s/hjbfbllnfhppnhjdhhbmjabikmkfekgf

It make Magento generates random js error.